# Why does my condition for my .push() in JSX return double values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am starting with a data file of objects in random order. They are of two types: Category and SubCategory.

I have managed to separate them and re-arrange them in order. But although each category exists only once in the original array, they are coming in in duplicates in the new array.

I am a newbie, so it has taken me a while to understand the logic, but I can't find the reason why the duplicates. Can you help me understand where/why this is happening?

**Sample Data**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "6181840f60c425f76e57b56c",
    "name": "Cakes ",
    "slug": "deli-sweet-cakes",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5b3",
    "product_skus": [],
    "rank": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b57f",
    "name": "Soda Water",
    "slug": "beer-cider-sodas",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b604",
    "product_skus": [],
    "rank": 3
  },
 {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b604",
    "name": "Beers & Ciders",
    "slug": "beers-and-ciders",
    "product_skus": [],
    "rank": 21
  }]
```

if an object doesn't have "parent_id" then it is a category.

```js
import data from "./data.json";

function App() {
  // Find non-special category objects ...
  let categories = data.filter((obj) => {
    return !obj.parent_id && !obj.is_special;
  });
  // Find non-special subcategory objects
  let subCategories = data.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.parent_id && !obj.is_special;
  });

  // create an empty container for them
  let orderedCategories = [];

  // re-arrange them
  categories.forEach((category) => {
    orderedCategories.push(category);
    if (!category.subCategories) {
      category.subCategories = [];
    }
    subCategories.forEach((subCategory) => {
      if (category._id === subCategory.parent_id) {
        category.subCategories.push(subCategory);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(orderedCategories);
  return null;
}
```

The resulting data is as I expected, except the list of sub categories repeats itself once more.

```js
name: "Beers and Ciders"
product_skus: []
rank: 21
slug: "beers-and-ciders"
subCategories: (6)

        0: {_id: '6181841060c425f76e57b57f', name: 'Hard Seltzer' ... 
        1: {_id: '6181841060c425f76e57b58f', name: 'Beer' ... 
        2: {_id: '6181841060c425f76e57b59f', name: 'Cider' ... 
        3: {_id: '6181841060c425f76e57b57f', name: 'Hard Seltzer' ... 
        4: {_id: '6181841060c425f76e57b58f', name: 'Ber' ... 
        5: {_id: '6181841060c425f76e57b59f', name: 'Cider' ...
```

Comment: I found nothing wrong in your code, maybe you should check if the data source is correct. By the way, it is better not to modify list item (e.g. catagory) in high-order functions like foreach, for better readability.

Comment: Thank you @YMSong I will inspect more carefully. Or perhaps test with different source Data. I am not sure I understand what you mean when you say "it is better not to modify list item (e.g. catagory) in high-order functions like foreach" , can you expand a little if you can? Thanks. I hope one day to be able to write code that is concise and clear.

Comment: I mean `categories.forEach((category) => { /* do not modify category here*  })`

Answer (score 0):

I realise now that there was an error in the syntax.

In my original code, I run two separate loops:

```js
// loop one:
  categories.forEach((category) => {
    orderedCategories.push(category);
    if (!category.subCategories) {
      category.subCategories = [];
    }
//loop two:
    subCategories.forEach((subCategory) => {
      if (category._id === subCategory.parent_id) {
        category.subCategories.push(subCategory);
      }
    });
```

Instead, it should be a single loop with a nested loop.

```js
categories.forEach((category) => {
    orderedCategories.push(category);
    if (!category.subCategories) {
      category.subCategories = [];
      subCategories.forEach((subCategory) => {
        if (category._id === subCategory.parent_id) {
          category.subCategories.push(subCategory);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

The original code returns the data twice. Nesting the loops returns correctly, only once.